# Microsoft.Owin.Hosting Creating RESTFull webAPI how to send objects to the controllers that handle the code

Tags: c#, rest, owin

I am trying to create an API for a service that is collecting Data. I want this API to be able to expose this data in a RESTful kind of web API.

I have the API working, using the following in my main code:

```
string baseUri = "http://*:8080"
 try
        {
            webAppli = WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseUri);


        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            WriteLog.WriteErrorLog("THREAD REST API server : ", ex);
        }
```

Startup Class is as follow.

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method is required by Katana:
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var webApiConfiguration = ConfigureWebApi();

        // Use the extension method provided by the WebApi.Owin library:
        app.UseWebApi(webApiConfiguration);
    }


    private HttpConfiguration ConfigureWebApi()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        return config;
    }
}
```

My controller class is as follow :

```
public class TagsController : ApiController
{
    // Simulate data
    private static List<Tags> _Db = new List<Tags>
        {
            new Tags(),
            new Tags(),
            new Tags()
        };


    public IEnumerable<Tags> Get()
    {
        return _Db;
    }


    public Tags Get(int id)
    {
        var Tags = _Db.FirstOrDefault(c => c.TagId == id);
        if (Tags == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(
                System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return Tags;
    }

}
```

What I can't figure out to do is to pass objects available in my main code to the controller. These objects contains lists of all the data I need to reply to the API queries. This is so I will not need Simulated data.

It is probably simple, but I tried many things event Named pipes and can't seem to make it work. Would you know the correct way.

Regards,

Comment: A possible way is to have some class that provides the data, and then:
1. Init it the controller's constructor (not recommended) OR
2. Preform a dependency injection.

Comment: Would you have a short Example on How to accomplis this? I usually do this using the class contructors or properties. In this case I do not see how to Do this as I do not declare and initialize the controller myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best answer, but is is the solution that worked for me.

To do what I needed I had to implement Interpeocess communication. I was trying to use Named pipes but I had problems with it.

The solution i used was to use TCP sockets.
I used the information here to create the code :

http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation you could:
1. Initialize some class that retrieves data in the controller (Not recommended - hard to test):

```
public class TagsController : ApiController
{

    private readonly IDataProvider dataProvider;

    public TagsController()
    {
        this.dataProvider = new DataProvider();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tags> Get()
    {
        return this.dataProvider.GetTags();
    }


    public Tags Get(int id)
    {
        var Tags = this.dataProvider.GetTags().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
        if (Tags == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(
                System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return Tags;
    }
}
```

2. OR Inject the dependency. You can find a good tutorial on how to implement a Unity resolver here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection. After the modifications the TagsController class looks like

public class TagsController : ApiController
{

```
private readonly IDataProvider dataProvider;

public TagsController(IDataProvider dataProvider)
{
    this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
}

public IEnumerable<Tags> Get()
{
    return this.dataProvider.GetTags();
}


public Tags Get(int id)
{
    var Tags = this.dataProvider.GetTags().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    if (Tags == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    return Tags;
}
```

}

And the `ConfigureWebApi` method becomes:

```
    private HttpConfiguration ConfigureWebApi()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IDataProvider, DataProvider>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

        return config;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this does work but it is not exactly what I want or I am missing something. This solution creates a new object that I can then use in the controller, it doesn't sends the object containing my values to the controller. It creates a new object with its default parameters on each query. It works well if I need to only query my database but not the state of the hosting service for example. I tried the suggested injecting solution which is nicely explained. Thx